# Gerador de matriz em Python

Tags: python, array, matriz

O programa faz o seguinte: eu digo o número de linhas e colunas que quero em minha matriz e depois atribuo um valor para cada coluna em cada linha, o problema é que parece que quando eu especifico o número de linhas através do append() ele cria uma "lista falsa", colocando os elementos da primeira sublista, em todas as outras:

```
lista = []
linha = []
nc = int(input('Quantas colunas? '))
nl = int(input('Quantas linhas? '))
for c in range(0, nl):
    lista.append(linha)
for c1 in range(0, nl):
    for c2 in range(0, nc):
        n = int(input(f'Número L[{c1+1}] C[{c2+1}]: '))
        lista[c1].append(n)
print(lista)
```

E caso eu tente colocar `lista[c1][c2]` ele dá o seguinte erro:

```
`lista[c1][c2].append(n)`
> zIndexError: list index out of range`

Output:
```

> ```
> Quantas colunas? 3
> Quantas linhas? 3 
> Número L[1] C[1]: 1
> Número L[1] C[2]: 2 
> Número L[1] C[3]: 3
> Número L[2] C[1]: 4 
> Número L[2] C[2]: 5
> Número L[2] C[3]: 6 
> Número L[3] C[1]: 7 
> Número L[3] C[2]: 8 
> Número L[3] C[3]: 9 
> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
> ```

`

Agora quando eu deixo definido a quantidade de linhas

```
lista = [[], [], []]
for c1 in range(0, 3):
    for c2 in range(0, 3):
        n = int(input(f'Número L[{c1+1}] C[{c2+1}]: '))
        lista[c1].append(n)
print(lista)
```

ele adiciona os números nas posições corretas:

> ```
> Número L[1] C[1]: 1
> Número L[1] C[2]: 2
> Número L[1] C[3]: 3
> Número L[2] C[1]: 4
> Número L[2] C[2]: 5
> Número L[2] C[3]: 6
> Número L[3] C[1]: 7
> Número L[3] C[2]: 8
> Número L[3] C[3]: 9
> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
> ```

**Agradeço muito se puderem me ajudar!**

Answer (score 4):

O problema é que no seu laço você cria *uma* lista e atribui ela a variável linha - e depois, você atribui essa mesma lista a cada posição na sua matriz.

Se criar uma lista nova em cada linha, já vai funcionar:

```
lista = []
nc = int(input('Quantas colunas? '))
nl = int(input('Quantas linhas? '))
for c in range(0, nl):
    lista.append([])
...
```

Pronto, com isso, em cada interação de `c`, uma nova lista é criada (quando o Python encontra a expressão `[]` - também poderia ser uma chamada a `list()`: dá na mesma).)

Comment: Obrigado, eu pensei que não podia colocar `[ ]` entre parênteses que ele ia aceitar como lista...

Comment: @AndrePaganotto Não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita se ela resolveu o problema

Answer (score 0):

A matriz está sendo criada de maneira errada ele deve ser criada assim:

```
lista = []
linha = []
nc = int(input('Quantas colunas? '))
nl = int(input('Quantas linhas? '))
for c1 in range(0, nl):
    linha = []
    for c2 in range(0, nc):
        n = int(input('Número L[{0}] C[{1}]: '.format(c1 + 1,c2 + 1)))
        linha.append(n)
    lista.append(linha)
print(lista)
```

> Mas por quê ?
>
> Porque assim as colunas (os número de cada) já vão direto para suas linhas prevenindo qualquer tipo de erro.

Answer (score 0):

Uma das formas corretas para se montar uma matriz bidimensional em python é utilizando o algoritmo apresentado abaixo. Perceba também que neste algoritmo utilizei a biblioteca `numpy` que deve ser previamente instalada.

```
import numpy as np

m = int(input('Quantas linas? '))
n = int(input('Quantas colunas? '))

matrizA = list()
for c in range(1, m + 1):
    linha = list()
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        while True:
            try:
                valor = int(input(f'Digite o {i}º elemento da {c}ª linha: '))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas valores inteiros!\033[m')
        linha.append(valor)
    matrizA.append(linha)

matriz = np.array(matrizA)
print(f'\033[32mA matriz gerada é:\n{matriz}\033[m')
```

Observe que quando executamos o algoritmo recebemos a primeira mensagem; `Quantas linhas?`. Neste momento devemos digitar a quantidade de linhas da matriz e pressionar `enter`. Posteriormente, recebemos a segunda mensagem; `Quantas colunas?`. Neste momento devemos digita a quantidade de colunas e pressionar `enter`.

Depois disso, recebemos a mensagem; `Digite o 1º elemento da 1ª linha:` . Neste momento devemos digitar o valor do elemento que corresponde a intersecção da primeira linha com a primeira coluna. Em seguida, devemos digitar os demais valores.

**Observação**

É bom notar que o **2º for** percorre o range que representa a quantidade de colunas e, para cada interação, inseri o valor capturado pelo `input` do bloco `while` na lista `"linha"`. Depois que a lista `"linha"` estiver completa (de acordo com o número de colunas previamente passado), o **1º for** inseri a lista `"linha"` dentro da lista `"matrizA"`.

Este processo é refeito até que a lista `"matrizA"` esteja completa.

Uma vez a lista `"matrizA"` estando completa, será submetida ao método `array` da biblioteca `numpy`, sendo convertida em uma **matriz** (array) bidimensional e, em seguida, será exibida.

Answer (score -1):

```
import random

lista = []
linha = []
nc = int(input('Quantas colunas? '))
nl = int(input('Quantas linhas? '))

for i in range(nl):
    for i in range(nc):
        randomNum = random.randrange(-5,5,1)
        linha.append(randomNum)
    lista.append(linha)
    linha = []
for k in lista:
    print (k)
```